# Перестал работать composer

Tags: windows, composer

Перестал работать composer на Windows 7
В окне терминала:

> Command: composer update
>
> You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact
>   on runtime  performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug The
>   "yiisoft/yii2-composer" plugin requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0,
>   this *WIL L* break in the future and it should be fixed ASAP (require
>   ^1.0 for example). Deprecation Notice: The
>   Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\MultiConstraint class is  deprecated,
>   use Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint instead. in phar://C
>   :/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstrain
>   t/MultiConstraint.php:17 Deprecation Notice: The
>   Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface interface is
>   deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface inst
>   ead. in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Packa
>   ge/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17
>
> [ReflectionException]   Class
>   Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist
>
> [ErrorException]   Declaration of
>   Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository
>   ::whatProvides() should be compatible with
>   Composer\Repository\ComposerRepo
>   sitory::whatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name,
>   $bypass   Filters = false)
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--lock]  [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no- progress]
>   [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--pre fer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs]
>   [--] []...
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\basic>

Переустановка ничего не дала. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Помогло:

```
composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins

Comment: Добавьте описание к вашему коду, чтобы было понятно что он делает